# why [setBackground] not working this script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my script-

```
    function dlColor()  {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      var columnO = sheet.getRange(2, 11, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
      var colors = [];  

      for (var i = 0; i < columnO.length; i++)
        colors.push([columnO[i][0] == 'DL' ? 'red' :
                     columnO[i][0] == '2' ? 'blue' : 'green']);
      var cell = sheet.getRange(2, 2, colors.length, 1);
      cell.setBackground(colors);


}
```

But when I put `cell.setFontColor` that works fine. How to use cell.setBackground actually? I read Google's document but can't find it out what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because its plural setBackgrounds. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBackground(String) Sets the background color of all cells in the range

Comment: Serge: setBackground takes a single value not an array. Besides, he can't use it because he has distinct values in colors.